# ELEGOO Mars failed prints every time

Tags: print-failure, elegoo-mars

So I just recently bought the ELEGOO Mars SLA Printer... the first model I made turned out okay. It was a small helmet. Only 3 out of the 9 small helmets made it; so I thought it was my bed... I re-leveled my bed and went for it again. Stuck to the FEP film. I did research and sanded the bed for better adhesion, nothing, changed my FEP film something printed but it was considered failed as there were some cracks. I changed settings on my printer software, ChiTu Box Slicing Software, I even did the recommended settings and custom settings I found on YouTube, and still nothing.

The only variables I have not changed are the FEP film again, as it could be too tight. And different resin. I'm currently using the Grey ELegoo resin... Or replacing my LCD Screen.. If y'all can help it would mean a ton!

Answer (score 1):

let's go step by step - and rule out the unlikely sources. Since you get at least *some* results, UV source and screen seem unlikely. Then you might want to make sure that the resin is ok. Let's try to put a droplet onto a sheet of paper/foil, which you tape down outside in the sun or under a UV light source - if it cures, the resin is ok.

The first real step is to check your bed leveling. Go exactly by the handbook - you might be a tad far from the bed, which leads to sticking to the film.

Then make sure your film is intact. You might need to swap resin vats to do that. in case the film is damaged, you have to swap it.